# How to import res folder of another app to your app in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to use layouts,values,dimens., etc of my previous project/app in my  new project. Basically, I want to import the whole res folder of my previous project into the new one. I know I can copy-paste the stuff I need, but in this case I need the whole folder as it is. So, is there an easy way to do it? I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Copy paste the whole folder . How hard could it be?

Comment: what is the meaning of "I need the whole folder as it is" ?

Comment: copy and replace your res folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract your resources to a libraryproject. Other projects can use this libraryproject as a dependency and can make use of the resources. Changes in the libproject will also affect other projects. So you don't have to copy&paste new code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use another project's res folder, you just need to copy and paste it under app folder of android studio project.

Answer (score 0):

You can't address the other Project Directory to your current project.
For Android Development all your resources need to be in your current project's directory within respective folder in "/res/" folder.